# I'm having trouble with my websites background

Tags: html, css

The desktop version looks good, but the mobile version is clipping the background. What I mean by this is that when I scroll it has the effect of two backgrounds.

I don't know if the problem is in the `css` or the `html` file.

```
body, html{
height: 1080px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: url("img/Mountain.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"> 
</script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css family=Montserrat:300,600,700i" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

Comment: delete `height:1080px`

Comment: If I delete the `height:1080px` it magnifies the background image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you set background-image for two element (html and body). A simple webpage layout like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can change the `height` value for the `body`, but not the `html`! The height value of HTML is always automatic. Therefore, after scrolling down 1080px, the body background ends and the html background is displayed. To solve the problem, just add the background to the body and remove height value.

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("img/Mountain.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, it fixed the clipping, but now the scaling of the background is off in the mobile browser.

Comment: `background-position: center` used in combination with `background-size: cover` to zoom the background images. And you used both. To solve this magnification problem, remove the styles above and add only `background-size: 100% 100%;` style.

Comment: Do I removed ~background-position: center and added ~background-size: 100% 100%~ ?

Comment: I suggest you remove `background-position:center` and `background-size:cover` and add `background-size: 100% 100%`.

Answer (score 0):

add this media code

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px){
  body, html {
    background-size:100% 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do I  add this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set bckgound for html and body. Only set the background for body.

```
body{ /* Remove html from this lie */
height: 1080px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: url("img/Mountain.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: If I remove the html the mobile version gets magnified